# Android Native Code Stack vs Dalvik VM / ART Stack

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android apps can execute C/C++ code using the Android NDK. All Android apps also run on the Android VM (i.e. Dalvik/ART).

My question is, does native code in Android apps use the same stack/heap as the Android VM?

i.e. In native code, we can create local variables and also variables via malloc/new, and these will be stored on the stack or heap respectively. But also my understanding is that the Android VM will create objects of it's own for bookkeeping. So does the native code and Android VM share the same stack/heap in memory?

Answer (score 1):

The managed JVM heap and the native heap are separate, but they are not completely isolated. Under the hood, JVM uses the same system calls, and via JNI, you can access java primitive arrays' memory.

As for stack, JVM and C share it per thread. But not all native threads are attached to JVM.